# Insurance CoInsurance company discloses financial claim information to the doctor office without consent, resulting in debt harassment

Tags: insurance

My Mother's insurance requires her to pay all doctor office fees upfront and then file an individual claim for reimbursement. Is it illegal for an insurance company to disclose financial claim information to the doctor office without consent, which has resulted in the doctor's office harassing my mother via phone, mail, and email?

Comment: What kind of "financial claim information" are you talking about?  It's perfectly normal for the insurance company to verify that the medical procedures they are asked to pay for were actually performed (and that the costs submitted for reimbursement are accurate).

Comment: And "without consent"? The doctor did perform something, for which he had consent. Are you sure you have your facts proper?

Comment: I have a feeling that Mother hasn't paid the doctor but submitted the claims. Doctor's office is now trying to get paid, knowing that she's supposed to get reimbursed by her insurance AFTER paying the doctor. Or she might have gotten a discount as a "cash" customer.